# Angular http.get/post with URL in data being passed

Tags: php, angularjs, post, get

I have the following http.get request...

```
$http.get("api/checkSave/"+ JSON.stringify($scope.programDetails)).then(function(data) {
....
});
```

In my programDetails object, there is at least one field that can have a URL in it. I thought the stringify would've properly encoded the object so it would get passed correctly to my PHP function. What seems to happen though is that the URL isn't sent properly. I get an error that the server responded with a 404 not found error. I manually tried removing the URL in the request (copied it to the browser and sent an empty string for the URL field) and the request was processed correctly - that's why I am thinking the stringify can't do what I need.

I also need to send this data via a http.post later to save the data in the object. Hopefully, whatever I need to do in the get will also apply when I call the post.

Should the stringify pass along the data correctly or do I need to encode it differently? I've been using stringify in other apps, but haven't had to pass a URL in the data.

If I need to do it differently, I would need to know what to do on the PHP side to decode it for processing. The examples I find for get/post all seem to pass individual variables and not an object and not with an URL in one of the variables. I've seen **encodeURIComponent** mentioned but wasn't sure if that's what I need to use instead and if so, then what to use on the PHP  side to decode it properly.

Comment: dont use encodeURIComponent instead of stringify, but combine them... You should also add it to a variable like '?json=XXXX'

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have much to do with the data consisting of a URL (only that a URL has a much better chance of having characters in it that have special meaning within a URL than other data).

The problem is that you are putting the data **into a URL** and URLs are not JSON texts.

To encode a string to put it in a URL use `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: ok, so I have tried to use $http.get("api/checkSave/"+ encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify($scope.programDetails))).then(function(data) and as long as the one field (that contains a url) does not have // (whether there's one or two) in it, the get will work. so if it contains 'yahoo.com' - the get works, if it contains '//yahoo.com' - the get fails. The '/'  are not being encoded within the whole object.

Comment: They should be. You can check by looking at the value before you pass it to `$http.get`. Possibly they aren't being encoded in the way that the web service expects, but there is no information about the web service in the question.

Comment: I outputted it to the console and the part that contains the url does seem encoded but it must be doing something when it passes it to the PHP so that it doesn't find my function to retrieve it the data. Here is the part where the URL is ks%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fyahoo.com%22%2C%22   I don't see '/' in it so maybe PHP isn't accepting it for some reason....since the GET error is returning URL not found...

Answer (score 0):

So it ended up that I had to replace the '/' in the fields that contained links and then it worked. Otherwise, the '/' was making it seem as though I was passing additional parameters in my get call.  Thanks for the help!